# Shifting UITableViewCell Content to the right

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there a simple way to shift cell content to the right?  Like a horizontal alignment or some sort of offset?

I'd rather not

- include a blank cell.imageView.image, or
- add spaces to each  cell.textLabel.text.

Any ideas please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `UIView` that contains subviews positioned where you want, i.e. set their frames. Then set the cell's `contentView` property to this parent view.

Comment: Yes, of course, thank you.  I'm more familiar with using a UILabel with a frame (which is a UIView) and I will do that.